# why is as.Date("06/10/2013", "%m/%d/%y") returning the year 2020?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

Like the title says,

```
>as.Date("06/10/2013", "%m/%d/%y") # returns "2020-06-2013
[1] "2020-06-10"
```

What is causing this?
I'm using windows with 32-bit RGui and the latest zoo package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `%y` is not `%Y`:

```
R> as.Date("06/10/2013", "%m/%d/%Y")   # note capital-Y
[1] "2013-06-10"
R>
```

Comment: wow. thanks for the quick response. You have helped me out in a number of questions I've referenced on SO already.  Can you link me to a good resource on the argument I was confused about in this question?

Comment: @cyclondude -- Sure. Check out `?strftime`. (Also, FYI, you can upvote answers that you find helpful -- whether to your own questions, or others')